# $index issue in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code for an angularjs app :

```
<li class="sm c" 
ng-repeat="msg in chat.msgs">

<p>{{chat.msgs[$index - 1].ts}}</p>
```

chat.msgs contains the following :-

```
{"1424093810600290":    
{"mId":"1424093810600290","ts":1424093810000,"s":"o_S"},
"1423736194723684":
{"mId":"1423736194723684","ts":1423736194000,"s":"o_R"}},
```

so on ..

How can I access chat.msgs[$index - 1] form ?
Because there is no index but a unique id.
I need to access the ts for the previous message.

Comment: Wouldn't "$index - 1" be a problem when your $index is starting from 0 or first index?

Comment: Even your <li> is also not closed.

Comment: I need to access the TS for the previous message at every current message for some check.

Comment: what about the first message ?

Comment: In that case your first message would show error because that wouldn't exist.

Comment: You need to change your approach regarding accessing previous message. Either place any condition or change the premise itself.

Comment: Can I access the mId for the previous message. Like chat.msgs[msg.mID].ts would give the current message ts. How can i get the previous message TS ?

Comment: Angular ignores errors in binding expressions, so the first message wouldn't be a problem for subsequent ones.

Comment: Yeah. I tried in plunker. It doesnt give an error for the first one that is why i Proceeded this way  [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nda591r0581CnJaeZSVK?p=preview)

Comment: How are your items ordered? How would you know what the "previous" item is, considering they are indexed with a key? If you do have a "previous" item based on the key, why not have a function in your controller that looks up the previous item?

Comment: That is what I wanted to figure out ? That if they have a key that matches to the mId can I somehow access the previous item

Comment: It's your data, how should we know how the second item relates to a previous one? I think your simplest solution is to convert your object to an array, and bind to that list instead

Answer (score 0):

You can get the key and value using [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#iterating-over-object-properties) like so

```
<li class="sm c" ng-repeat="(id, msg) in chat.msgs">
```

if you need the id, though you can rewrite your code like this:

```
<li class="sm c" ng-repeat="msg in chat.msgs">
  <p>{{msg.ts}}</p>
</li>
```

Comment: I tried this : chat.msgs[id].ts gives the respective TS but id-1 still doesnt give the result

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $index use :

```
<li class="sm c" 
ng-repeat="(key, value) in chat.msgs">
<p>{{processValue(value.ts)}}</p>
</li>
```

write function in your controller which will accept and store value in scope variable, whenever the function get called, you will have previous value in scope variable and new value in function parameter.